# Keep track of meeting attendance without receiving email responses in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to set up a large meeting in Outlook 2010.  I don't want to receive the many responses as emails clogging my inbox, but I do want to be able to keep track of who is coming (for example, by selecting the meeting in my calendar and seeing their responses).  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hopefully, you will not be able to see a large meeting attendance responses from the attendees as a single view. But opening each calender invite may notify you the list of attendees who are accepted the invite. It is marked as 'Tick' mark against the attendee who accepted the invite. It should be shown in the right pane of the calender invite.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2016 has the option you're looking for: *File* --> *Options* --> *Mail*. Under the *Tracking* header you'll find the option *Update tracking information, and then delete responses that don't contain comments*.

[image: Outlook options]

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013:

- File, Options, Calendar
- Auto Accept/Decline...
- Check on Automatically accept meeting requests and remove canceled meetings

[image]

Comment: This is not the solution that was asked for.

Comment: Novell GroupWise will do exactly what he wants easily, but Outlook is a sub-par product. Do you have a better answer? Because the best one can do in Outlook often is to offer workarounds not solutions.

Comment: The question was from the perspective of the organizer. Your answer is from the perspective of an invitee to the meeting.

Comment: How do you know my perspective? Organizer that does not auto accept meetings will have the calendar item appear in their inbox. This is a way to know who is attending or declining. So your assessment is not correct.