# Message Trace Reason

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

After the meeting was created and the rooms were selected, no message about the event was delivered.

```
Message Trace result : Reason: [Stage: OnCreatedEvent][Agent: Meeting Message Processing Agent];MeetingMessageProcessingAgent; Suppressing delivery of response meeting emails as owner marked response not wanted.
```

Can anyone help me why the exchange did not send the given message?

[image: Screenshot of Outlook error]

Comment: This sounds like the response email from participants to the meeting, which was suppressed from coming in to the meeting organizer. Maybe it's related to the setting in Outlook to delete such emails and simply add them to the calender, see https://superuser.com/a/1379395/368970

Comment: "owner marked response not wanted" seems reasonably self explanatory. The person who sent the request may have the "request responses" option turned off. In the meeting request creation menu go to Meeting -> Attendees -> Response Options (dropdown) and check the "request responses" option.

Comment: Do all meeting attendees not receive the meeting request?